# FULLTEXT CONTAINS search returns no results in SQL SERVER 2014 with multiple search terms

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, full-text-search

When I try to use multiple search terms in a CONTAINS clause I get no results.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Address
WHERE CONTAINS([Address].*,'"Detroit"') AND CONTAINS([Address].*,'"48226"')
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481)

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Address
WHERE CONTAINS([Address].*, ' "Detroit" AND "48226" ')
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481)
```

The first query returns almost 20k rows.  The second, which should be logically the same returns nothing.  When I try the same test on my 2012 server, it returns the same number of rows, so I'm pretty sure it isn't syntax.

My version is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-CU6) (KB3144524) - 12.0.4449.0 (X64) 
    Apr 13 2016 12:41:07 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

There is no stopword list set up for this fulltext index.

The QUERYTRACEON 9481 forces the optimizer to use the cardinality estimator for SQL Server 2012 - this solves another issue we have had with FULLTEXT indexes and TOP in 2014, but makes no difference in this case; the queries return the same number of rows with or without it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out these are not logically the same; the second requires the results to be in the same column, while the first is across all columns